# Constrained Delaunay Triangulations in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, delaunay

It is possible to make Constrained Delaunay triangulations in PostGIS (PostgreSQL)? I have a Polygon and I need to make internal triangulation like this:

[image]

I tried to use ST_DelaunayTriangles but is not possible to add constraints like "triangulations only internal polygon"

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have posted an answer to nearly the same question overhere: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/st-delaunaytriangles-polygon-with-holes/241373#241373

Answer (score 2):

There is now [ST_ConstrainedDelaunayTriangles](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ConstrainedDelaunayTriangles.html) in postgis 3.